# How do I git clone a http repo behind a socks proxy?

Tags: git, proxy, git-clone, socks

I can tunnel the ssh if I want to clone from a ssh repo, but what happens if I want to clone a http repo (accessible only via the socks proxy)?

For example, cloning https://git.repo.com/repo.git via socks proxy 127.0.0.1:1080.

I am currently using `proxychains4 git clone` to do this (setting proxy in proxychains conf). I know there is a global flag where to can change the global proxy setting for git but that is not desirable since I only would use it one time (I can change it back afterward but it feels less legit that way).

Comment: So, https://git.repo.com/repo.git is accessible only via the  socks proxy?

Comment: Can you give an example of this kind of repository?

Comment: It would be pretty hard to set up an example and give it to the public I guess. I will need to create a VPS and then open a socks5 port on the server and create a private DNS. I think the problem might be ALL_PROXY=xxx doesn't proxy the dns search.

Comment: I can just give u the real socks5 proxy and repo I am using because it is obviously a secret at my company. @BernardoDuarte